# Converting char[] to uint16 (unsigned short) gives wrong numbers

Tags: c++

I have a problem converting a char array to a unsigned short (UInt16). My converting techniques seems to be wrong...
Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Symbols 0x1210 :
    char test[2];
    test[0] = 0x12;
    test[1] = 0x10;

    unsigned short n;
    memcpy(&n, test, sizeof(unsigned short));

    int i=0, arrToInt=0;
    for(i=1;i>=0;i--)
        arrToInt =(arrToInt<<8) | test[i];

    /*
    Now are:

    n = 4114
    arrToInt = 4114

    But! -> 0x1210 == 4624
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way (without) reversing the char array?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Look up big and little endian.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness, your number is stored LSB first

Comment: To your actual question... reverse the loop?  But see the others for why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
    arrToInt =(arrToInt<<8) | test[i];
```

Comment: @SeriousK. -- I know my answer is trivial, but if it helped you, please select it as the best answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left, which should turn it to green.